# How can I cache a list of objects in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching

Spring boot does not cache the list of objects. My code looks like the one below, the method is inside a @Service

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "myObject", key = "#id")
public List<MyObject> filterObjects(Long otherObjectId){
    //Do something
}
```

However, this code does work

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "myObject", key = "#id")
public MyObject getById(Long id){
    //Do something
}
```

I have already searched Stackoverflow but none of the solutions work for me. I tried also

```
@Cacheable("myObject")
public List<MyObject> filterObjects(Long otherObjectId){
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: Spring cannot create a proxy for the private method, and thus caching won't work. The method should be public to enable caching. Also in filterObject method shoul be another key "key = "#otherObjectId""

Comment: You're right, I wrote it wrong here, my method is public

Comment: Did you use @EnableCaching over Service annotation?

Comment: No, I have the @EnableCaching annotation in the main spring boot class. That cann not be the problem, as the second piece of code I wrote in the message works

Comment: So, did you try to change the key as I mentioned before?

Comment: Yes, but it's not solved

Comment: The last what can i mention is that cacheNames should be unique. try to change it, please

Comment: It is unique the chacheName

Comment: Can you show code how you invoke filterObjects method? And do you have any configuration class for cache config? Please post in too.

Comment: I just call the method from another class that has the service autowired. I don't have any cache configuration class

Answer (score 0):

Your key should be `otherObjectId` as follows:

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "myObject", key = "#otherObjectId")
public List<MyObject> filterObjects(Long otherObjectId){
```